# About perfect numbers

Tags: python, for-loop, perfect-numbers

```
a = input('input a number :')
for i in range(1,int(a)):
    b=0
    for z in range(1,int(a)):
        if i == z :
            continue
        elif i%z == 0:
            print('i = ',i,'z =',z)
            b += z 
            print('b = ',b)
            if b == i:
                print(i,'is a perfect number')
```

My question is about that why this program gives output '24' as 'perfect number' ?

I was coding a 'perfect number finder with for loop' machine.My question is about that why this program gives output '24' as 'perfect number' ?

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. Iterate over all values less than `a` (or optimally less than or equal to the square root of `a`) and for each value that's a divisor of `a` add it to the sum of divisors. Finally, after the iteration is complete, compare the sum of divisors with `a`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "why this program gives output '24' as 'perfect number' ?" Because `b` is equal to `i` one of the times that it's checked. Please read [ask], and [carefully study](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) what happens when the code runs; this is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the sum of the divisors against the number itself inside the loop, **before** you finish iterating over all divisors. In the case of 24, its divisors are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12. But, their sum up to (and including) 8 is 1+2+3+4+6+8 = 24, so the condition `b == i` evaluates to true. Instead, you need to perform this check once, **after** the loop is finished. Also, you should only check for divisors up to `i-1` (this can be improved upon mathematically to `floor(i/2)`, but let's get the basics first), not `a`.

Here is a slightly cleaned up version of your code, with this correction

```python
a = int(input('input a number :'))
for i in range(1, a):
    b=0
    for z in range(1, i):
        if i%z == 0:
            b += z
            print(f'i = {i}  z = {z}  b = {b}')
    if b == i:
        print(i,'is a perfect number')
```